# Check security descriptor of a client using thread impersonation

Tags: windows, acl, impersonation

I am trying to check access rights of a file of a client to impersonate it with the thread.
I checked this example on Microsoft dev center but it seems to have lots of problems https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379648(v=vs.85).aspx

Also I am having a piece of code but it always returns false

```
      PACL file_dacl = NULL;
      AutoLocalFreeSDescriptor psd;
      DWORD dstatus = GetNamedSecurityInfoA(fname2.buf, SE_FILE_OBJECT, DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION,
            NULL, NULL, &file_dacl, NULL, &psd.psd);
      if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dstatus) {
         return false;
      }
      AutoCloseHandle security_token;
      // Not sure if OpenAsSelf (3rd arg) should be true or false
      BOOL bstatus = OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, true, &security_token.stoken);
      if ((! bstatus) && (GetLastError() == ERROR_NO_TOKEN)) {
         bstatus = OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &security_token.stoken);
      }
      if (! bstatus) {
         return false;
      }
      GENERIC_MAPPING f_perms_map = {
         FILE_GENERIC_READ,
         FILE_GENERIC_WRITE,
         FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE,
         FILE_ALL_ACCESS
      };
      DWORD file_exec_access;
      if (perm == 'r') {
         file_exec_access = FILE_GENERIC_READ;
      }
      else if (perm == 'w') {
         file_exec_access = FILE_GENERIC_WRITE;
      }
      else { // perm is 'x'
         file_exec_access = FILE_GENERIC_EXECUTE;
      }
      MapGenericMask(&file_exec_access, &f_perms_map);
      PRIVILEGE_SET priv_set;
      DWORD priv_set_size = sizeof(priv_set);
      DWORD granted_access = 0;
      BOOL have_access = false;
      bstatus = AccessCheck(psd.psd, security_token.stoken, file_exec_access, &f_perms_map,
            &priv_set, &priv_set_size, &granted_access, &have_access);

      DWORD d = GetLastError();
      LPSTR messageBuffer = nullptr;
      size_t size = FormatMessageA(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
          NULL, d, MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT), (LPSTR)&messageBuffer, 0, NULL);

      std::string message(messageBuffer, size);

      //Free the buffer.
      LocalFree(messageBuffer);
      if (bstatus) {
         return (have_access != 0);
      }
      else {
         return false;
      }
```

Is the problem related to the client itself or the problem is with the code?

Comment: return false because `AccessCheck` fail (in this case - which is error code ?) or because `have_access` false ?

Comment: An access check requires an impersonation token, so a process token needs to be duplicated. Also, the check fails if the security descriptor doesn't have owner and group security identifiers. The owner affects the evaluation of an (implicit) owner-rights entry. It should also have the label information, in case the label denies read-up, write-up, or execute-up access to subjects at a lower integrity level. Also, if read access is not granted, you have to retry without read-attributes in the mask. If that succeeds, generic read access is granted if the parent directory grants read-data access.

Comment: Also, this doesn't take into account an open that uses backup semantics with either SeBackupPrivilege or SeRestorePrivilege enabled. Ultimately the simplest and best check for file access is to just call `CreateFile` while impersonating to let the file system figure all of this out for you.

Comment: Also, use wide-character `GetNamedSecurityInfoW` instead of ANSI `GetNamedSecurityInfoA`. The ANSI API is all but deprecated (it should be). Figure out how best to use Unicode for your requirements. Sometimes it's best to use `WCHAR` (UTF-16) everywhere in Windows development. But you may have UTF-8 inter-op requirements that make it better overall to use UTF-8 and convert string parameters to UTF-16 just for WinAPI calls.

Comment: @RbMm because accesscheck fails and the error is “An attempt has been made to operate on an impersonation token by a thread that is not currently impersonating a client”

Comment: @eryksun do you have any example of this because I cannot figure out what are all of this

Comment: Edit your question to show what you've done so far to correct the problems with your calls to `GetNamedSecurityInfo` (i.e. getting all of the required information) and getting an impersonation token from the primary token that's returned by `OpenProcessToken`. Also, remove the pointless call to `MapGenericMask`, since `file_exec_access` contains no generic rights.